# How to scale the image to fit the image view in ios?

Tags: ios

I put an image in an image view in xcode and set "scale to fit" mode, but I find that the image doesn't fit the size of the image view. So how can I make the image to fit the size of the image view in ios?

Below is the screenshot of storyboard.
 [image: Here is my screen shot.]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your image view config in Interface Builder, and a screenshot of the result on the device/simulator?

Comment: @ev0lution I just post the screenshot, but I cannot provide the config of interface builder, because I use storyboard instead.

Comment: It's still called Interface Builder within Xcode ;) What is the frame of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of methods to play with:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 12):

To do this in your storyboard, select your `UIImageView`, open the Attributes Inspector, and select either "Aspect Fill" or "Aspect Fit" from the "Mode" drop down menu.

[image: UIImageView Content Mode]

Comment: It helps me a lot.